# AWS EKS service account authentication

Tags: amazon-eks

Is there a different way other than asking for get-token to authenticate on EKS?

Today my .kube\config looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-datXXa: X==
    server: https://XXX.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
    namespace: xx
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
  name:arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us00000-east-1:0:cluster/user
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
```

Allthough the service I am trying to leverage just supports basic token or client-key-data authentication.

Therefore I want to have a user that I could connect with for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-datXXa: X==
    server: https://XXX.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
    namespace: xx
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
  name:arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXX:cluster/XXX
users:
**- name: test1
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CXXXX==
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CXXXX==**
**- name: test2
  user:
   token: bGsdfsdoarxxxxx**
```

Tried creating a serviceaccount but I am not able to create a .kube/config

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Azure Kubernetes Service, AWS EKS uses only one type of authentication, that is webhook token based authentication which is implemented by AWS IAM Authencticator and uses native kubernetes RBAC policies for authorization.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-auth.html

A Service Account provides an identity for processes that run in a Pod, and maps to a ServiceAccount object. When you authenticate to the API server, you identify yourself as a particular user. Kubernetes recognises the concept of a user, however, Kubernetes itself does not have a User API.

In AWS in case your pod needs to access any aws services, you create a service account with required IAM roles and have to attach that to the pod. In that case, you can't use service account for client side authentication.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html